# Does Google Safe Browsing mark WHOLE WEBSITES or INDIVIDUAL PAGES as phishing?

Tags: google

Does Google Safe Browsing mark WHOLE WEBSITES or INDIVIDUAL PAGES as phishing? If I create 1 phishing page, will all pages of my site be penalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whole website will be marked for phishing. You can go through their FAQ here to understand what they mean by website [Link to FAQ](https://support.google.com/transparencyreport/answer/7380435?hl=en&ref_topic=7380433)

EDIT :  "In this data, a “website” refers to the hostname or fully qualified domain name of a URL (e.g., `somehost.example.com`). When we scan a site and identify malicious hosts, we count each distinct host."

Comment: Use Google Search Console to get notifications and more information about the URLs that have triggered the website getting marked.